# Can I configure Visual Studio Code's C/C++ extension to display errors in all files?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code's C/C++ extension (v1.17.5, on Visual Studio Code 1.83.1).  As far as I can tell, the Problems pane will display errors in a C++ source file only when I have that file open in the editor.

Instead, I'd like the Problems pane to always display all errors/warnings in my project, even if they're in source files that are not open.  I'd find that much more useful (and extensions for other languages such as Python or Haskell typically work this way).  It is possible to configure the C/C++ extension to do this?  Or was it simply not designed to work this way?

Comment: just compile your project

Comment: Are you talking about the messages displayed by IntelliSense in the editor or compilation errors?

Comment: @Gerhardh: I'm talking about compilation errors displayed in the Problems pane.  I just edited the questions to make that clearer.

Comment: To me, this question smells like lack of research.

Comment: @JesperJuhl for newcomers it's not always apparent, because technically one can have errors while building without IntelliSense reporting them if IntelliSense is not configured correctly.

Comment: @AdamDingle as far as I know the problems panel uses IntelliSense to find issues. You need to search how to configure it correctly with your project and it'll show you project-wide errors even if the code is not compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to my question rioV8 wrote "just compile your project".  Ah, now I see - if I run the command "Run Build Task" (Ctrl+Shift+B) then the project attempts to build, and the Problems pane shows compilation errors in all files.

It wasn't obvious to me that I needed to perform this step, since I'm used to other extensions (e.g. Pylance) that report errors without the need to build explicitly.